# Creating and assigning a value to lvalue when the rvalue depends on the lvalue

Tags: objective-c

I was a bit surprised to see this code not throw a compile error, and was a bit curious as to why it works.

`packet` is an object that contains a byte-array, and I read it with these custom methods. The function will read the bytes from `location` up to `length`.

Usually, I just write:

```
uint8_t byte;
byte = *(uint8_t*) [packet getBytes:&byte startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(byte)];
```

but was surprise to see that this following line also seems to be valid.

```
uint8_t byte = *(uint8_t*) [packet getBytes:&byte startingFrom:&byteLocation length:sizeof(byte)];
```

Can anyone illuminate me as to how the right hand side of this statement can depend on the left hand side to have been created? Are there any potential pitfalls that I should be worried about even though I am not getting any compile time errors (for iOS 8 application)? Thanks

**Edit:**

Without getting into the specifics too much of why this function is written the way it is (which is mostly just for reducing lines of code on the page), this function does just copy a value into `byte` from an array of bytes, and also returns it as a value. It also auto advances the byteLocation by the length parameter, so you can just call these lines one after another to parse a byte data array into all it's value components.

The packet object contains this method:

```
- (nonnull void*)getBytes:(nonnull void*)buffer startingFrom:(nonnull NSUInteger*)location length:(NSUInteger)length {
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(*location, length);
[self.data getBytes:buffer range:range];   // self.data is just an NSData*

*location = range.location+range.length;

return buffer;
}
```

That return value is just a convenience to trigger some KVO notifications when used in other cases, not this particular case.

Also, yes while this example is using Objective-C to describe the question, you could easily write these functions in C / C++, which is why they were originally tagged C/C++ and see similar behavior. I figured someone who understands more about how these statements get broken down to the assembly level might enlighten me. As stated in the comments, I suspect that the lvalue here is getting created first, the rvalue is then evaluated, and finally the rvalue is assigned to the lvalue storage area, but would like to know if that theory is correct or there is another explanation.

Comment: This is neither C++, nor C. Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense. `bytes` should _either_ be written to inside `getBytes:startingFrom:length:` _or_ be assigned to the return value, _not both_. Where does this method come from? What class are `data` and `packet`?

Comment: This hurts my head. First - I don't know what byteLocation is or how it's set up but &byteLocation feels wrong. Second - You're... writing one byte - into byte, then it returns... a pointer to the data?  that you're dereferencing , assigning the first byte back into byte that you already copied by getting the only one byte from...

Comment: This situation actually does depend on C's rules for variables, @TimČas, although the ObjC bits may be obscuring that.

Comment: Answer: (I think).  Assumption that for reason this returns a pointer to the raw data, which is weird.  Anyways, This works because you're only asking for one byte.  You're copying it using the getBytes:startingFrom:length: method.  Then you're copying it again by the dereference at the end.  This is only true if my assumptions about the function are correct, which is a weird assumption

Comment: I don't know much about the formal rules, but it's unsurprising to me that this *could* work: byte is not used; the address of byte (&byte) is used. Even with the value of byte indeterminate, the address that future value will be stored should be known. Likewise, sizeof(byte) can be determined at compile time long before this statement is reached.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Still, it's not a C question.

Comment: @StevenFisher Yeah, I suspected that is what was happening. I guess I was just surprised that any allocation of the lvalue was made before the processing of the rvalue. But perhaps the compiler makes the lvalue first, performs the rvalue computation, and only finally does the assignment of the rvalue to the lvalue.

Comment: @Tim Cas: This could be rephrased as a pure C question pretty easily: `uint8_t byte = getBytes(&byte, sizeof(byte));` I think it'd still be valid.